# Is Cancan's accessible_by my best choice for altering admin scope on the fly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

Situation: On my site, I have a comment model, with a deleted field. Users cannot see deleted comments, but I would like to allow admins to see deleted comments, if they choose to. This will be accomplished by having a scope for users with the admin role which allows them to view comments with the deleted field set to false, as well as true.

Question: Is Cancan's accessible_by method my best choice for doing so? From what I've read, it sounds like it will facilitate exactly what I'm trying to do, but, I don't want to implement something that is inefficient, if there is a better method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For separating out the queries to only pull the records needed based on role, accessible_by is perfect for this case.

If you want to give them the choice (the admins) of viewing or not viewing deleted comments then the accessible_by scope alone might not be enough, might be better to create scopes on the model using accessible_by with a switch for whether or not they have chosen to see or not to see the deleted comments.

```
@user.comments.viewing_deletes(true).accessible_by(current_ability)
```

Where viewing_deletes is a scope on comments that finds comments which are 'deleted' as well as the rest for true and only non-deleted comments for false.

Comment: Thank you trh, I had actually overlooked the aspect which makes this approach unreasonable - being locked into using default_scope for many models. However, your answer would work if this were not the case, so thank you.